# Ordered query fast with index but slow when I add a where clause

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, where-clause, non-clustered-index

I have this query

```
SELECT [f].[Id], [f].[Code], [f0].[Path]
FROM [FunctionalAssets] AS [f]
INNER JOIN FunctionalAssetStructurePath AS [f0] ON f.Id = f0.FunctionalAssetId
WHERE [f0].[StructureConfigurationId] = 'A8A41B14-0A35-45D3-2A2B-08D904A3CD0B'
ORDER BY [f0].[Path], [f0].[Name]
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY
```

I created an index on the table FunctionalAssetStructurePath with the columns : structureConfigurationId, path and name.
This query is fast (100ms), no problem.

But when I have this query :

```
SELECT [f].[Id], [f].[Code], [f0].[Path]
FROM [FunctionalAssets] AS [f]
INNER JOIN FunctionalAssetStructurePath AS [f0] ON f.Id = f0.FunctionalAssetId
INNER JOIN FunctionalAssetStructure AS [f1] ON f.Id = f1.FunctionalAssetId
WHERE [f0].[StructureConfigurationId] = 'A8A41B14-0A35-45D3-2A2B-08D904A3CD0B'
    AND [f1].[StructureId] = 'ec40fc59-13e3-4e32-7290-08d90639e607'
ORDER BY [f0].[Path], [f0].[Name]
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY
```

The query is very slow (+2000ms).

If I remove the index, the first query is slow (+2000ms) but the second is fast (200ms).

I find that very strange. Do you know why ? And how to dix it?

### UPDATE 1

[Image with my index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfvh0.png)

Thx

Comment: What DBMS are you using? What does the execution plan show you? (You should put more work into picking your table aliases, BTW; `f` and `f0` are bad choices when you're trying to read the code, especially when you're unfamiliar with it like the readers here will be.)

Comment: Also, the second query contains two match conditions in two separate tables (`f0` and `f1`), where the first query only has to match one condition in a single table. The second clearly would have to do much more work.

Comment: @KenWhite I copied the query from entity framework, that's why I have the alias f and f0.
The problem is on the oder by not the filter.
In the first query I have 2M+ items that need to be sort and it is fast (thanks to the index).
In the second query, the filter return 70 000 items and it is slow (but if I remove the index it is fast).
In both cases, if I change the "order by path, name" by "order by (select 1)", the queries are fast.
So the probem is with the order by (I think).

Answer (score 0):

For your first query, you are not even pulling any value from the FunctionalAssetStructure table, so why would you be joining it.  I would remove it completely

Also, if your filtering is based on the inner join table, I would swap the layout for readability about the priority of tables.   The flow would be similar in both queries, just adding your secondary AND clause to the location of its INNER JOIN

In order to better optimize this query, I would ensure you had the following indexes on the tables and IN the column order provided

```
Table                          Index
FunctionalAssetStructurePath   ( StructureConfigurationId, [Path], Name )
FunctionalAssets               ( id, code )
FunctionalAssetStructure       ( FunctionalAssetId, StructureID )
```

Rewrote with more meaningful aliases to match table context

```
SELECT 
        fa.Id, 
        fa.Code, 
        fasp.[Path]
    FROM 
        FunctionalAssetStructurePath fasp
            INNER JOIN FunctionalAssets fa
                ON fasp.FunctionalAssetId = fa.Id
            INNER JOIN FunctionalAssetStructure fas
                ON fasp.FunctionalAssetId = fas.FunctionalAssetId
                AND fas.StructureId = 'ec40fc59-13e3-4e32-7290-08d90639e607'
    WHERE 
        fasp.StructureConfigurationId = 'A8A41B14-0A35-45D3-2A2B-08D904A3CD0B'
    ORDER BY 
        fasp.[Path], 
        fasp.Name
    OFFSET 
        0 ROWS 
    FETCH 
        NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY
```

Again, the first query never needed the additional join to the FunctionalAssetStructure table and COULD have been removed, but with the additional JOIN condition (moved from the where to INNER JOIN), you can see the index helps optimize that component.  If this significantly helps, would be nice to know the final querying speed for you.

Comment: For the first query, it was a bad copy/paste. In my scenario the FunctionalAssetStructure INNER JOIN is not there.
I confirm that I have the mentionned indexes (in the same order).
What is strange is that in the first query I have to sort +2 millions items and it is fast (thanks to the index with path and name column).
In the second query the filter return 70 000 items so the sort need to be done only on 70 000 items and it is slow. But if I remove the index (with path and name colums) the query is fast.
If I change the order with "order (select 1)" the two queries are fast.

Comment: @KoosMos, it sounds like the table FunctionalAssetStructurePath does NOT have the index on ( StructureConfigurationId, [Path], Name ).  A single multiple-field index.  This should return almost instantaneously since the WHERE is on the StructureConfigurationID, and the path/name are already also sorted following suit.  Since a covering index, it should never have to go to the data pages for anything else and resolve quickly.  Please confirm the index has all 3 columns, not 3 individual indexes of each, but 1 single index having all 3 columns.

Comment: I confirm that I have one index with these 3 columns (I update my post)

Comment: @KoosMos, your updated post only indicates that your index is on post and name, not the StructureConfigurationId, post AND name, all 3 columns is critical for the performance.  The first column qualifies the WHERE, the remaining 2 to optimize the ORDER by clause.

Comment: If you opens the picture in my post. You will see that I have the 3 colums.